# with nextjs do we only use axios now with SSG and SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

So just to understand what is the best practise with Nextjs? Do we stop fetching data with axios and etc in our functional components and we do it with the SSG/SSR functions?

I just started Nextjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js, the choice of where to fetch data depends on your specific requirements.

Client-side rendering may not be ideal for marketing websites due to potential SEO issues caused by delayed content. However, it is often used for fetching data in dashboards or pages that aren't indexed.

Static Site Generation (SSG), allows you to fetch data at build time and serve it as static data. This eliminates the need for roundtrips to an API for every user request.

Server-Side Rendering (SSR), is useful when you require the desired content to be present in the initial response. It is particularly beneficial when you need to make API requests with sensitive information that shouldn't be exposed in client-side code.

The beauty of Next.js is that you can fetch your data how you want and consume it in your typical React components.

You can use almost any data fetching library which wraps the fetch API, since Next.js automatically polyfills it for you.
Here are the official docs on data fetching:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching